# How add textarea in post worrdpress?

Tags: wordpress

How programmatically add a new field to the post? I want so that it can be filled by the addition of the post.

For example

http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_5414528_13475829.png

Comment: Is this what you were thinking of: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the plugin mentioned in comments (or a similiar one) and then select through the screen options of admin panel (located up and right on your screenshot) to see this field on the listing page (the one you have opened in the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i have mistake. Actually, i`m need another.

I want add new textarea, when creating new post, and put that value in `shot_describe` FROM `my_table`.

For example

http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_6603091_13478644.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create meta boxes in post and can save value in database

please see my following code:

I have set 3 Parts:

```
 1)  function add_meta_box_post()
{
    add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Custom Meta Box", "add_meta_box_markup", "post", "normal", "high", null);
}
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_meta_box_post");
```

For Creating Text-area in post do below :

```
2) function add_meta_box_markup($object)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");

    ?>
        <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>  <label for="meta-box-text">lable name</label></td>
        <td>  <textarea name="meta-box-textarea" id=""  rows="5"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </div>
    <?php  
}
```

For Saving Text-area value of Post in Database

```
3) function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $slug = "post";
    if($slug != $post->post_type)
        return $post_id;

    $meta_box_text_value = "";

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-textarea"]))
    {
        $meta_box_textarea_value = $_POST["meta-box-textarea"];
    }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-text", $meta_box_textarea_value);


}

add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);
```